# Can a .NET WCF application work with more than one network adapter?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, networking

We have an existing .NET Framework 4.7.1 application that communicates with a .NET server in a domain through WCF/NetTcp. We now need a third-party external hardware to send data to it. However, this hardware will ideally not be in the corporate network, but on its own network, so a second network card (*) would be installed on the PC:

```
                      ------ Network 1 (AD domain) ------------
                     |                                         | 
                     |   -----------------                     |
                     | | PC Win10        |                     |
                     | |.NET application |                     |
                     | | WCF             |                     | 
Network 2            | |-----------------|                     | 
CLIENT APP* ---------> |ETH2*        ETH1| ------> .NET SERVER |
                     |  -----------------                      |
                     |                                         |
                      ------------------------------------------
* = new
```

**Question**
Can this be done in application level, ex. with an additional app/process and named pipes between them, or even better, in a single application (the existing one)? Or should it be done at network layer, ex. bridging or another solution?

Answer (score 0):

NETTcpbinding is only applicable to the internal network environment. If you want to use internal network services from the outside, it is recommended to publish an external network address from the inside so that the outside can access it, or you can add binding to make your service available for external access.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but question is if and how can a WCF application, acting as both client and service, handle the fact that the machine on which it runs has 2 different network adapters. The service must know on which adapter it should listen.